# Trying to JOIN 5 tables, having issues

Tags: mysql, select

I'm fairly new to both mysql and php so I am still getting my head around it all, so please bear with me.

I basically have a site where users can make topics, and tag tagwords to their topics, I am trying to join the tables so when I query for the POSTS, it can also show the tag information in there.

```
"SELECT u.user_id, u.username, u.profile, topic_tags.tag_id, tags.tag_id, tags.tags,
       p.post_id, p.post_content, p.post_date, p.post_topic, p.post_by, p.invisipost 
FROM `posts` p
JOIN `users` u on p.post_by = u.user_id
JOIN `topics` t on p.post_topic = t.topic_id
WHERE p.post_topic='$id'
INNER JOIN `tags` ON topic_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN `topic_tags` ON topics.topic_id = topic_tag.tag_id
WHERE topic_tags.tag_id = topics.topic_id";
```

Like I said I am still very new to this so if you could offer any advice I would be much appreciative.

EDIT: here is the code that calls the tags

```
<?php
        $topic_id = $rows['topic_id'];
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topic_tags WHERE `topic_id`='{$topic_id}'");
        while($rowd=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {   
            $tag_id = $rowd['tag_id'];
            $fetch_name = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tags` WHERE `tag_id`='{$tag_id}'"));
        ?>
            <div id="topic-tagged"><?php echo ucwords($fetch_name->tags);?></div> 
        <?php
        }       
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

All the wheres should be at the end:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, u.profile, 
topic_tags.tag_id, tags.tag_id, tags.tags,
   p.post_id, p.post_content, p.post_date, 
 p.post_topic, p.post_by, p.invisipost 
FROM `posts` p
JOIN `users` u on p.post_by = u.user_id
JOIN `topics` t on p.post_topic = t.topic_id
INNER JOIN `tags` ON topic_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
INNER JOIN `topic_tags` ON topics.topic_id = topic_tag.tag_id
WHERE p.post_topic='$id' and topic_tags.tag_id = topics.topic_id
```

This is the corrected query statement based on your original question. I am still not sure if the last part is correct though. You might want to run this in your database directly and see if you get the results you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm getting "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  on line 76" which is "$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){"

Comment: Can you try running this statement directly against MySQL  (and not through PHP) ? You can use PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench etc.

Comment: "Unknown column 'topics.topic_id' in 'where clause'" is what I got.

Comment: does your topics table have a topic_id column ?

Comment: yes, topic_id is in topics and TOPIC_TAGS, the tags are associated with the topics via topic_tags table.

Comment: will it be possible for you to post the structure of all of your tables? try "show create table tablename" in MySQL.

Comment: POSTS
post_id
post_content

TOPICS
topic_id
topic_content

TOPIC_TAGS
tag_id
topic_id

TAGS
tag_id
tags

USERS
user_id
username
profile

Comment: I think you need another table that stores tags for a post or you need a table that associates POSTS with TOPICS. In either case, you probably don't need the user table for your original query.

Comment: well the tags aren't for posts, they are so I can display the TOPIC TAGS in each post result, kinda like on a forum how the topic is "fred" then replies are "re: fred" the users table is in there to show the username and poster avatar.

Comment: in that case you need some sort of association between posts and topics.

Comment: they are currently associated, just i can't get the tag info to display within the posts, everything else displays fine, originally topics had a category field and that displayed for posts, but adding the tag tables has thrown everything off it seems.

Comment: I added to my original post the code used to fetch the tags, maybe I am doing something wrong there?

Comment: do you think you can create your schema on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/ and populate it with some sample data. That would be helpful in debugging the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few rules when writing SQL.  The `where` clause comes after the `from` clause.  In addition, tables can only be references in an `on` clause *after* they have been placed in the `from` clause.  And, a query only has one `from` statement and one `where` statement.  All `join`s are placed in the `from` statement.

Two good practices are to use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table (which you do sometimes).  And, don't mix `join` and `inner join`.  They are synonyms, but only one should be used in a query.

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.username, u.profile, tt.tag_id, ta.tag_id, ta.tags,
       p.post_id, p.post_content, p.post_date, p.post_topic, p.post_by, p.invisipost 
FROM `posts` p join
     `users` u
      on p.post_by = u.user_id join
     `topic_tags` tt
      ON p.post_topic = tt.topic_id join
     `tags` ta
     ON tt.tag_id = ta.tag_id
WHERE p.post_topic='$id';
```

Finally, I'm pretty sure that you do not want `and tt.tag_id = topics.topic_id`.  This is comparing a `tag_id` to a `topic_id`.  They are not referring to the same thing.  I think the `join`s as shown above are sufficient for your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was joining tag_id to topic_id because topic_id is in TOPICS, tags are in TAGS, and then TOPIC_TAGS is where the tag_id and topic_id join them up.

I tried what you suggested and I am still getting "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Comment: I don't think you need the topic table in the query.  You can join directly from `posts` to `topic_tags`.  (The `on` condition was wrong there.)